# How do I raise an Android Intent using Qt Necessitas SDK?

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt-necessitas

I'm developing an Android application using C++ and Qt Necessitas SDK.
My application should load/save files and I want to handle it using Android actions ( so that I can target Google Drive as well as Dropbox etc... )

The question is... how do I raise Intents ( and which Intent should I raise to share/import my files ) from C++ ?

Rationale: how do I load and save files ( either custom mimetype, or pdf ) using Qt Necessitas on Android?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a complete newbie to java and I know nothing of JNI, but apparently this link will explain how to [use the JNI to] use intents in your QT for Android applications: http://community.kde.org/Necessitas/JNI

It looks pretty straightforward, but I'm afraid I don't yet understand what I'm reading enough to give you a better answer to your question.

Sources:

- groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-qt/U3eHis9mLrg
- groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-qt/UpgBRz8Imwo

Another option for a some things (opening websites, making phone calls, possibly opening local PDFs and images) would apparently be QDesktopServices::OpenURL() - although that seems to give open-only access (ie, opening the resource but not pulling any data back from it).

I'm interested in this so that I can use the barcode scanner app "ZXING", which has an intent-as-url at http://zxing.appspot.com/scan - I don't know what other little secrets are out there...

HTH until someone can give you a better answer

(2 links disabled due to insufficient reputation)